# Internet Explorer Scrolling Bug in Z-Indexed Element

Tags: internet-explorer, scroll, z-index

I have created a popover menu that displays a list of links in a navigation area. Here is the relevant css for the containing div:

```
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 200;
```

There is javascript attached to the div such that if the navigation menu extends below the bottom of the screen, it adds overflow-y scrolling and resizes it to fit. By chance, these navigation menus are generated adjacent to another scrolling element and extend over it.

This works perfectly if you use the mouse wheel to scroll. However, if you click and drag the scrollbar, the part of the menu that extends over the other scrolling element is not updated until you release the scrollbar and interact with either the nav menu or the element underneath.

How do you force the element to update? The page has a transitional/loose doctype. The above defect is present in internet explorer, but not chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by doing this (with jQuery):

```
menu.scroll(function (evt) { 
    jQuery('div.dropdownmenu')
       .css('height', menu.height()+1)
       .css('height', menu.height()-1) 
});
```